# Opera 18 doesn't load bold variants of custom fonts on the page

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, opera

On our site we have a few fonts. I embed them like this

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri Light";
    src: url("fonts/calibri/light/calibri-light.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/calibri/light/calibri-light.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/calibri/light/calibri-light.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/calibri/light/calibri-light.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    src: url("fonts/calibri/regular/calibri.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/calibri/regular/calibri.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/calibri/regular/calibri.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/calibri/regular/calibri.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri Bold";
    src: url("fonts/calibri/bold/calibri-bold.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/calibri/bold/calibri-bold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/calibri/bold/calibri-bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/calibri/bold/calibri-bold.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams";
    src: url("fonts/caviar-dreams/regular/caviar-dreams.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/regular/caviar-dreams.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/regular/caviar-dreams.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/regular/caviar-dreams.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold";
    src: url("fonts/caviar-dreams/bold/caviar-dreams-bold.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/bold/caviar-dreams-bold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/bold/caviar-dreams-bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/caviar-dreams/bold/caviar-dreams-bold.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "TeX Gyre Adventor";
    src: url("fonts/tex-gyre-adventor/regular/tex-gyre-adventor.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("fonts/tex-gyre-adventor/regular/tex-gyre-adventor.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/tex-gyre-adventor/regular/tex-gyre-adventor.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/tex-gyre-adventor/regular/tex-gyre-adventor.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The problem is that the `Caviar Dreams Bold` doesn't load. It just doesn't appear in the **Sources** tab in the Inspector (all others are shown). Chrome 32 works well. No errors or warnings are thrown.

I use the font like this:

```css
#feedback input[type="submit"] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Caviar Dreams Bold", "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

The Calibri font is used by Opera instead.

### Update 1

It seems that `Calibri Bold` is ignored too. Why are the bold fonts ignored?

### Update 2

Don't be surprised that I don't specify `font-weight: bold` in the `@font-face` queries: for some reasons it didn't work and I had to do my job fast. So that fact that different `font-family` doesn't being load seems very interesting to me. And it's more interesting that as we know that Opera's rendering should work as Blink do.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Caviar Dreams Bold font actually contain small caps? If not, Opera probably concludes the request glyps can't be found and will fall back to Calibri. What happens if you remove the `font-variant: small-caps;` rule?

**Edit:** Interesting bug report on why Blink doesn't fall back to "small-caps synthesis" (as it is apparently called): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=298970 Seems like removing the SVG font from your `@font-face` rule will do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. That worked. On Blink only Mac Chrome renders all as needed, every other variant fails like this.

Comment: That's probably because the browser decides to fake the small caps by taking normal caps and reducing them in size — a common fallback.

Comment: @RoeIN Yeah, I thought about this. The question is why the same renderer works differently even in one browser on different platforms.

Comment: This apparently is a recent bug in Blink. Looks like it's fixed in Chrome but hasn't found its way to Opera yet.